# Flash Android screen with accurate timing

Tags: android, android-ndk

I must create an Android app that flashes the screen on/off with accurate timing in order to send Morse-code-like messages to an external device via visible light. My experiments so far have failed since the OS appears to interfere with my "postAtTime" requests and mess up my timing.

Does anyone have suggestions on how I can flash the Android screen on/off (black/white) at least every 50 milliseconds with plus or minus 5% accuracy?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

### SplashScreen.java

```
package some.pkg.name;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

    Handler handler = new Handler();

    // run a thread after 5 seconds to start the home screen
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

           finish();

           // start the home screen
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, TargetActivity.class);
            SplashScreen.this.startActivity(intent);

        }

    }, 5000); // time in milliseconds (1 second = 1000 milliseconds) until the run() method will be called

}
```

}

### splash_screen.xml

```
       <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="@drawable/splash_image"/>
```

### In Manifest file

```
 <activity android:name=".SplashScreen"      
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN">
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER">
        </category></action></intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try with an animation over a View. You can have a black background with a full screen white view, and animate the View's visibility on and off.

Answer (score 0):

Using `postAtTime()` would add too much overhead. You can try using Animation or even try old, loop/sleep based approach. For Animation [see docs here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/package-summary.html) (tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidAnimation/article.html)), for the loop/[sleep](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#sleep%28long%29): alibrate your app on device by doing i.e. 10 flashes and seeing how long it takes. Then you know how much time single flash take. Adjust `sleep()` accordingly to get required flash rate. ALternatively, you could try Handler's `postDelayed()`, but it'd be rather ineffective in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use CountDownTimer class and its onTick Method.

u can set the number of milliseconds it should flash the time 
write your code for animation logic inside onTick menthod of CountDownTimer.

You just need to Write a class that extends CountdownTimer and then call countdowntimerOBJECT.start() in onCreate of ur activity.
You can have a black background with a full screen white view, and animate the View's visibility on and off.

Comment: Thanks to all for the suggestions. I will try to test each one. However, I have a follow-up to all these suggestions... Won't Garbage Collection, other apps and other background acrtivity constantly mess with my accurate timing needs? Is it feasable to ask an Android OS for this type of accurate timing? Thanks.